# ¿Cómo detectar el cierre de un formulario secundario desde el formulario principal?

Tags: vb.net

> Quisiera su apoyo, me explico:
>   1. Mi frmPrincipal llama a travez de un boton al frmSecundario, con  FrmSecundario.Show()
>   2. Al mostrarse el frmSecundario yo agrego nuevos registros.
>   3. Cierro la ventana frmSecundario con me.Close() el cual se ejecuta con el boton cerrar.

**frmSecundario**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> 4. Y es aqui en donde quiero capturar el cierre del frmSecundario para poder ejecutar mi funcion en el frmPrincipal:

**frmPrincipal**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 Public Function Autocomplete(ByVal campo As TextBox, ByVal procedure As String) As Boolean
        Dim correcto As Boolean = False
        Try

        obj_MantenimientoGeneral.ds.Clear()
        obj_MantenimientoGeneral.BuscarDescripcion(procedure)
        Dim col As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
        For i = 0 To obj_MantenimientoGeneral.ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
            col.Add(obj_MantenimientoGeneral.ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0).ToString)
        Next
        campo.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
        campo.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col
        campo.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
        correcto = True
    Catch ex As Exception
MsgBox("Se produjo un error : " & ex.Message)
        correcto = False

    End Try

    Return correcto
End Function
```

> txtTipProductoNuevo es el campo tipo de producto del frmPrincipal

```
obj_Listas.Autocomplete(txtTipProductoNuevo, "sp_ListarTipoProducto")
```

**BuscarDescripcion de la Función **

```
Function BuscarDescripcion(ByVal sql As String) As Boolean

        Dim correcto As Boolean = False
        Try
            Abrir()
            enunciado = New SqlCommand(sql, obj_conexion) With {
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            }
            da = New SqlDataAdapter(enunciado)
            da.Fill(ds, "Item")

            enunciado.ExecuteNonQuery()

            correcto = True

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Se produjo un error : " & ex.Message)
            correcto = False
        Finally
            Desconectar()
        End Try

        Return correcto
    End Function
```

Comment: Tu función en donde lo tienes, en el frmPrincipal o en el frmSecundario??

Answer (score 0):

Espero haber entendido tu pregunta...

Si cierras tu frmSecundario en un botón tendrías que hacer esto.

```
 Private Sub btnCerrar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCerrar.Click
        obj_Listas.Autocomplete(txtTipProductoNuevo, "sp_ListarTipoProducto")
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
```

Pero si cierras tu aplicación con X entonces tendrías que capturar el evento frmClosing

```
Private Sub frmSecundario_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
         obj_Listas.Autocomplete(txtTipProductoNuevo, "sp_ListarTipoProducto")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Añadí imagenes para que se entienda mejor.

Comment: Aun no me queda tan claro que es lo que pretendes, Abres el frmSecundario a tra ves de un botón, insertas datos, después de insertar N datos cierras el frmSecundario y al final en tu frmPrincipal quieres filtrar los datos (las que ingresaste anteriormente)? Es asi?

Comment: Correcto, quiero tener los nuevos datos agregados de frmSecundario en el frmPrincipal.

Comment: por ultimo para poder aterrizarlo ya, los datos que insertas en el frmSecundario los alamcenas en una base de datos?

Comment: si, este es el sp: alter procedure sp_ListarTipoProducto
as
select Descripcion from TipoProducto
order by Descripcion 
go

Comment: Siendo asi no entiendo para que quieres capturar el evento del cierre del frmSecundario, no será más fácil filtrar los datos que están almacenados en la base de datos nomas??

Comment: Lo que pasa que el AutoCompleteStringCollection tienen los datos anteriores y no los datos agregados en el frmSecundario, entonces quisiera actualizar el AutoCompleteStringCollection con los nuevos datos solo cuando se cierre el frmSecundario

Comment: Quieres decir que al aar de alta en el frmSecuandario y cerrar la ventana no refresca los datos de la tabla y por consiguiente no se actualiza los datos en tu AutoCompleteStringCollection ?

Comment: si refresca la tabla pero tendria que ejecutar de nuevo la funcion para que el autocomplete me muestre esos nuevos datos de la tabla y queria hacerlo luego del cierre del frmSecundario.

Comment: De alguna manera tiene que refrescar tus datos en AutoCompleteStringCollection, el evento de cierre de formulario lo tienes arriba en la respuesta, pueder ver este link http://net-informations.com/q/faq/autocomplete.html para ver si te sirve... Lo que quieres hacer es llenar dos componentes diferentes a la vez, tendrías que agregar tus datos a la BD y a la misma vez llenar tu AutoCompleteStringCollection, asi como lo quieres hacer no veo factible solo llenar los datos en tu BD porque en ningún momento lo cargas en tu colección , de alguna manera tiene que refrescar.

Comment: Revise la información del link(Autocomplete TextBox working with Database values VB.Net) y cambie mi código, pero aun asi solo carga los datos agregados en el frmSecundario si cierro el frmPrincipal, ya que el código esta en el frmPrincipal_Load, existe alguna manera de cargar los datos del frmSecundario en el frmPrincipal sin cargar nuevamente el frmPrincipal.